# How can I make an armor stand in minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need an armor Stand because I'm enchanting lots of armor and running out of chests so if you know how I need to know

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, no, but according to the [Minecraft Wiki,](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor_Stand#History) MC PE *will* be receiving armor stands in Version 1.2, the "Better Together Update" scheduled for around November.

[image: Armor Stand Update History]

Answer (score 2):

As of September 20, 2017 with Minecraft Bedrock 1.2 (The Better Together update) armor stands are now included in the game. 
[image]

Which means, that you should be able to find it in your crafting menu if you have acquired all of the required items. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly (as far I know), armour stands aren't present in PE edition minecraft.

They should be present in other versions, however.

Comment: Aww I was really looking forward to learning how let me know if u find out cause I used the zombie trick and he kept running away!!!!!

Comment: Ok, @user196720! Mojang should release information on updates, however.

Comment: U can call me gr